# Combine left half and right half of two circular images react native

Tags: react-native

Hello I hope everyone is doing well, I ran into some issues and I need to know how to display a half from two different flag icons each. Any help will be appreciated, see the image attached.

[image: This is the Intended result (half of each flag)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the best way to do that is to make the circles in some editor and then put it on your code in an `<Image />` tag and give it the styles, because you will have 2 img by circle, and if you have 5 circles it will be 10 imgs for example.

But, if you want to try with 2 imgs you'll have to wrap 2 `<Image />` tags in `<View>` and give styles to the last one. In [THIS](https://codepen.io/enzzoperez/pen/mdrxdJN) example in codepen you can take a look and replicate the code for RN

Comment: Thanks, I was able to come up with a solution with a few adjustments to the code you sent.